# How to implement advanced search functionality in Spring MVC with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot. I am implementing the microservices architecture.
I have two entities driver and car. There is one to one relationship between driver and car. One driver can select only one car and one car can be selected by only one driver.

I want to implement advanced search functionality. It should be possible to search for drivers by their attributes (username, online_status) as well as car characteristics (license number, car name, etc). I am using Database as H2 (In memory). I want to avoid nested if and else.

What is the best way to do this in Spring Boot?

Comment: How do you connect to your H2 database? Are you using Hibernate & JPA or Spring JDBC?

Comment: Please take a look at: https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa

Comment: @MatMat By using spring.h2.console.enabled=true

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is enable hibernate-search module in your code. For this aim you could use Indexed and Field annotation.

example below

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Car {
    @Column(name = "name")
    @Field
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "license_number")
    @Field
    private Integer licenseNumber;


}
```

And after that you could use search functionality in your service layer

```
@Service
public class CarServiceImpl implements CarService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Car> search(Sting name, String licenseNumber) {
        FullTextSearchBuilder builder = new FullTextSearchBuilder(entityManager, Car.class);
        builder.appendAndQuery(name, "name");
        builder.appendAndQuery(licenseNumber, "licenseNumber");
        FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = builder.createFullTextQuery();
        return (List<Car>) fullTextQuery.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have approx 16 attributes (driver + car). I don't want to specify each and every field. Also, I want to retrieve a list of drivers having car name "XYZ". Search criteria can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CriteriaOperator to create advanced search.
Add this to your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.apulbere</groupId>
    <artifactId>crop</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Next define a DTO containing all the fields you want to use for search. For example:

```
public class DriverSearch {
   private StringCriteriaOperator username;
   private StringCriteriaOperator carName;
   private BooleanCriteriaOperator isOnline;
}
```

And use the DTO in the controller. Additionally, you have to map fields fro DTO to the ones from entity:

```
@GetMapping("/cars")
List<DriverSearchResult> findAll(DriverSearch searchCriteria) {
    return cropService.create(Driver.class, searchCriteria)
        .match(Driver_.username, DriverSearch::getUsername)
        .match(Driver_.isOnline, DriverSearch::isOnline)
        .join(Driver_.car)
            .match(Driver_.carName, DriverSearch::getCarName)
        .endJoin()
        .getResultList()
        .stream()
        .map(this::mapToDriverSearchResult)
        .toList();
}
```

Note, that `Driver_` is a metamodel generated by Hibernate.

The request will look like `/cars?userName.eq=bob&carName.like=Toyo&isOnline=true`. All the query params are optional.